# Dynamic Alert Generates Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using the following code to handle an alert:

```
ts.getDriver().SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Which is working fine but I have occasional scenarios where the alert does not always pop up. Can anyone offer a solution? I can't seem to find the correct syntax to handle the condition in C#.

Thanks,

Comment: Does it throw a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: NoAlertPresentException: No Alert is active     I am calling a method which handles an alert that pops up during my test but not every scenario triggers the alert pop up so i am trying to figure out the syntax to write an if else or some other kind of conditional statement to handle when the alert is being fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use try catch to handle that. Even the [`AlertIsPresent`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/ExpectedConditions.cs#L576) is implemented as such.

```
try
{
    ts.getDriver().SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
}
catch (NoAlertPresentException)
{
    // do nothing...
}
```

If you want to hide that ugliness, you can wrap that inside an extension method :

```
public static class SwitchExtensions
{
    public static IAlert AlertOrNull(this ITargetLocator locator)
    {
        try
        {
            return locator.Alert();
        }
        catch (NoAlertPresentException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().AlertOrNull();
if (alert != null)
    alert.Accept();
```